# Ubuntu keeps changing my DNS to 127.0.0.53

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, dns, vpn

I installed `expressvpn` with Chrome extension. And even when I disable the VPN my system keeps changing my DNS to `127.0.0.53` and I have to manually change it back to `192.168.1.1` for internet to work. And I have to do this every hour or so.

Ubuntu changes `/etc/resolv.conf` to this

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

**What I have tried:**
I tried to set DNS globally but it didn't help

```
/etc/systemd/resolved.conf

#  This file is part of systemd.

[Resolve]
DNS=192.160.1.1
```

*I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS*

**UPDATE: Here is** `ls -al /etc/resolv.con`

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.con
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 53 Jun 15 16:20 /etc/resolv.conf
```

**UPDATE 2**
I had also installed `dnsmasq` a while ago

Answer (score 2):

The annoying thing here is that you basically have to "hack" either Network Manager or systemd-resolved to configure a custom DNS.

Here is a way to do it using a package called `resolvconf`. [This package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/resolvconf) ensures that `/etc/resolv.conf` is updated with your custom DNS info.

Install:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install resolvconf
```

Check service is running: (if not enable and start)

```
$ sudo systemctl enable resolvconf.service
$ sudo systemctl start resolvconf.service
$ sudo systemctl status resolvconf.service
```

Edit config file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

Add the following lines: (your custom and Google for fallback)

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save the file and restart the service:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart resolvconf.service
```

Check that your custom DNS have been added to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

[Source](https://www.tecmint.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-debian/)

Comment: Good answer, but you should also disable NetworkManager from trying to update DNS or does resolvconf takes care of that?

Comment: Resolvconf overrides the generated `/etc/resolv.conf` file by always placing the contens of `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` at the beginning of the file. So it shouldn't be necessary. Also, I don't know anything about NetworkManager, but feel free to add this step. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Generated by NetworkManager

Means that DNS is **not** taken care of by Systemd but by NetworkManager, so modifying `systemd-resolved` config will not do anything, [here is a way](https://serverfault.com/a/810639/604280) to set that up

Answer (score 1):

The file /etc/resolv.conf is intended to be a symbolic link for networking, dnsmasq, etc. to work properly. Yours is faulty so let’s fix it:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

I suspect that the improvement will be immediate; please check:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns, you’re all set.